# How to calculate running average with 1 formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do you calculate running average with 1 formula in Google Sheets?

In the example below, Data column is given (and dynamically generated/appended); Average_so_far column is desired.

| row index | Column A [Data] | Column B [Average_so_far] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.5 | 1.25 |
| 3 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 4 | 1.5 | 1.5 |
| 5 | 1.25 | 1.45 |

How do you generate the values of running averages in 1 formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function. Try-

```
=MAP(B2:B6,LAMBDA(x,AVERAGE(B2:INDEX(B2:B,ROW(x)-ROW(B1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And it works. Will just wait for a day or two in case others want to answer with different solutions. Cheers